# What to do when an acceptance test has varying user choices and you want to test each of them

Tags: testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm writing some acceptance tests for a donation form. I'm using [Codeception](http://codeception.com/). For the sake of this example, lets say that the donation form has 3 parts:

1. Enter your personal information
2. Enter either Credit Card and Direct Transfer
3. Submit and receive e-mail confirmation

For the acceptance test I'd like to test the whole process--for both credit card AND direct transfer. Steps 1 and 3 are essentially the same between the two donation processes, but--obviously--you can't run the second step by itself (the donation form wouldn't submit without step 1).

So I'm wondering, would it be "normal" in this case to write two tests (e.g. `canDonateWithCreditCard()` and `canDonateWithDirectTransfer()`) that both test all three parts of the process? Even though that's partly testing the same thing twice?

If not, what would be the preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable at my work we have a sizable automation suite where the same pages get executed multiple times, because of scenarios similar to what you outlined above.

The only caveat I would mention is when building your tests (I don't know how codeception works) but look to build your tests using something along the lines of the page object model (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) this will mean even though you have multiple tests that may implement the same scenarios each test doesn't have its own implementation of those steps.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your approach. 
1. You can create two different test cases performing the action.
2. You can have a logic in your test to pass the mode of transfer as an argument     to the method and perform activities accordingly. 
It's always ideal to use Page object model to encapsulate all actions in each page class and also to avoid redundancy.
If both Credit card and Direct transfer actions navigate to a new page, create a new object of the page according to the argument passed, and call the method to do the transfer action. 
A simple page object class can be created like this: 
http://testautomationlove.blogspot.in/2016/02/page-object-design-pattern.html